# How to split a float number string into two lists?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, split

I have the string `'1234.12'` and I want to split it into two lists: `[1234]` and `[12]`.

The only way I know is to make the whole string into a list by using `.split()` with a comprehension: `[n.split() for n in '1234.12']`, which gives me:

```
[['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['.'], ['1'], ['2']]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s = '1234.12'

a,b = ([int(x)]  for x in s.split(".",1))

print(a,b)
```

Or just do it in 2 parts, map to int and just wrap in lists after:

```
s = '1234.12'

a, b = map(int,s.split(".", 1))

a,b = [a],[b]
```

Which will both give you the two numbers cast to int and wrapped in lists:

```
a -> [1234]
b ->  [12]
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me ask you what's the usage of 1 inside the split function?

Comment: @wa7d, we only have a single `.` so no point looking beyond that when we find the first, it just mean basically split on the first once you find and don't look for anymore

Comment: Why does python ignore a leading zero? I tried a number with a leading zero and it print everything after the zero

Comment: @wa7d, leading 0 means octal in python2 and invalid syntax in python3

Answer (score 3):

You can split the string with dot and the n use `map` function to convert the result to list:

```
>>> map(list,s.split('.'))
[['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['1', '2']]
```

And of you want the result as `int` you can use `int` function within `map` :

```
>>> map(int,s.split('.'))
[1234, 12]
```

Note that in this case you can access to the numbers with a simple indexing and don't need to put each of them within a list.

Comment: the OP wants `[1234] [12]` not `[['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['1', '2']]`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yep, but since the question is a bit vague I suggested 2 way.

Comment: lol none are the right way, the question is very clear, they want what I have in my answer ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yeah ;-) I know but I think that there is no need to put the number within list when he can access them with indexing.Anyway putting a number in a list would be a easy task ;-).

Comment: Unless you need the number in a list ;)

Comment: @Kasramvd is it also possible to have the result as int and in two different lists? like your second suggestion.

Comment: @wa7d, no, you cannot do it with map, you need to use the first example in my answer or something similar

Comment: @wa7d That's what Padraic suggests.

Answer (score 1):

To explain why what you were trying wasn't working,

```
n.split() for n in '1234.12'
```

is effectively equivalent to

```
for n in '1234.12':
    n.split()
```

When you iterate over a string like that, you end up getting the individual characters, so we can also say that is equivalent to:

```
for n in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '.', '1', '2'):
    n.split()
```

So since the `split` was only given a single character at a time, it wasn't functional. You want to move the split to the string itself:

```
n for n in '1234.12'.split()
```

At which point you don't need the comprehension anymore.

```
'1234.12'.split()
```

The last piece was explained elsewhere... `split`, by default, splits on whitespace, so to tell it to split on a period instead:

```
'1234.12'.split('.')
```